# How to generate symbol map in gwt using maven?

Tags: maven, gwt, command-line

I want to generate symbol map file in gwt using maven commandline option? I tried with -extra WEB-INF/classses but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to specify maven plugin configuration values/options.

Here you have the general approach: [LINKE](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)

Besides that you have to know the plugin prefix that you can find on the GWT plugin page (there are several GWT maven plugins)

EDIT: added a gwt plugin example:
Just define the ${} snippets in your gwt property section and you will be fine.

```
<!-- The GWT compiler configuration 
References: 
Plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin
Optimizing the build: http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-gwt-compiler-for-better-builds
System properties: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/JavaSystemPropertiesAndGwt
 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>              
                <execution>                    
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <id>bla</id>   
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal> 
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <module>com.bla.BlaProd</module>
                        <mode>htmlunit</mode> 
                        <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                        <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
                        <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${gwt.war}</warSourceDirectory>
                        <webappDirectory>${gwt.output.bla}</webappDirectory>
                        <gen>${gwt.output.bla}/${gwt.gen}</gen>
                        <extra>${gwt.output.bla}/${gwt.extra}</extra>
                        <fragmentCount>8</fragmentCount>
                         <extraJvmArgs>-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false</extraJvmArgs>
                         <localWorkers>4</localWorkers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried setting gwt-maven-plugin configuration values but not able to generate symbol map. I tried even with style(PRETTY,DETAILED) but I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Through the maven plugin config, it's easy, just <extra>FOLDER</extra>  to the plugin config and the folder will contain symbol map. I use it with success, just make sure the plugin is linked to the compile goal such that it's run. I can post the my maven snippet if you want... But I though you want to realize it through the command line

Comment: I tried <extra>Floder</extra> but I am not able to generate symbol map but I see rpcPolicyManifest in WEB-INF/deploy/module_name folder. I'm using mvp4g on the client side. I don't know whether its mvp4g that is causing this issue.

Comment: In my case the folder is not even getting created.

Comment: @Kkishere: strange that no folder is created. Mvp4g has nothing to do with. Please use the above maven config. Try adding <extraParam>true</extraParam>, or add "Dgwt.extraParam=true" to the <extraJvmArgs> section (see the plugin link in my config above) Run the plugin through mvn gwt:compile.

Comment: After spending around two days found the Junit.gwt.xml dependency is used in Gingitsu library. So after removing it symbolMaps are generated in WEB-INF/deploy/module_name/symbolMaps folder.