# How to generate symbolmap in gwt mvp4g project?

Tags: maven, gwt, mvp4g

I am using Mvp4g on the gwt client side. I want to generate symbolMap that is used by RemoteLogging Servlet but when I try to generate symbol map using mvn clean install and specifying -extra folder_name property in gwt-maven-plugin configuration, I don't see the symbolMap files. It is not a plain gwt app but its gwt with mvp4g. I don't know whether its mvp4g that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvp4g generates Java code on the client side. This happens before the compiler translates the code to JavaScript. Check your settings. May be this post helps. [How to generate symbol map in gwt using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202372/how-to-generate-symbol-map-in-gwt-using-maven)

Update:

I use this maven configuration:

```
<gwt.output>myPathToTheProjectDirectory/output</gwt.output>
<gwt.gen>genSources</gwt.gen>
<gwt.extra>extra</gwt.extra>
```

And this for the maven-gwt-plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <id>bla</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
          <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
          <compileReport>true</compileReport>
          <warSourceDirectory>${gwt.war}</warSourceDirectory>
          <webappDirectory>${gwt.output}</webappDirectory>
          <gen>${gwt.output}/${gwt.gen}</gen>
          <extra>${gwt.output}/${gwt.extra}</extra>
          <fragmentCount>8</fragmentCount>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false</extraJvmArgs>
          <localWorkers>7</localWorkers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

In case I execute maven:compile, the symbolmaps are listed inside the folder `myPathToTheProjectDirectory/output/extra/symbolmaps`.

Comment: I see rpcPolicyManifest folder created in deploy folder but not symbolMaps folder.

Comment: I see the symbol map generated in .junit_symbolMaps folder but not in the deploy folder. I don't know why it is generating in that folder. I have also removed Junit.gwt.xml from all module files.

Comment: Have you checked that no third party lib contains a reference of JUnit.gwt.xml?

Comment: After spending around two days found the Junit.gwt.xml dependency is used in Gingitsu library. So after removing it symbolMaps are generated in WEB-INF/deploy/module_name/symbolMaps folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this: `<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />`

It solves the problem for me.